# What does fgets do?

Tags: c, fgets

It is not equal:

```
fgets (answer, 256, stdin);

if (strncmp(answer, "sta", 4) == 0)
  printf("omg, it's equal");
```

This code is:

```
fgets (answer, 4, stdin);

if (strncmp(answer, "sta", 4) == 0)
  printf("omg, it's equal");
```

Why? It is because in the first, answer doesn't have \0 at the 4th place I guess (if I change it to 3 instead of 4 it works). But what does fgets do? String answer in the first is `str \whitespace*253\0"`? And in the second it is `str\0`? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgets` (unlike `gets`) includes the trailing `\n` corresponding to the return pressed at the end of the line. If you put `3` as the limit it truncates the string, discarding the `\n`.

From the manpage:

> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream  and
>         stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by `s`.  Reading stops after an
>         EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.
>         A  terminating  null  byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the last character in
>         the buffer.