# C program add individual digits, lower and uppercase letters, and other characters

Tags: c

I'm trying to have my program print these:

- count each individual digit (0-9)
- count each individual alphabet letter (a-z and A-Z)
- total count of any other kind of character

The output is supposed to be the values stored in (10+26+26+1=) 63 counters
Question was : Count the number of various individual English alphabets (both lowercase and uppercase). Also count the total number of characters.

My professor hasn't really been helpful as well as my TA as they never really got into this; they just assumed we knew C right off the bat and unresponsive in emails.
Sorry to all others as I am new to this site and trying to learn. Thanks for your patience.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define MAXLINE 1000
    main()
    {
    char str [MAXLINE];
    int ndigit, nlower, nupper, nother;
    int c;
    printf("Enter any text with numbers or other characters if you like: ");
    fgets(str,MAXLINE,stdin);
    ndigit = nlower = nupper = nother = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                    ++ndigit;
            else if (c >= 'a'  && c <= 'a')
                    ++nlower;
            else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'A')
                    ++nupper;
            else
                    ++nother;
    }
            printf("Digits : %d Lowercase Letters %d Uppercase Letters %d Other characters %d\n", ndigit, nlower, nupper, nother);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple typo in else if. change second 'a' to 'z' and second 'A' to 'Z'

Comment: What is actually the Question?

Comment: You're aggregating all the upper-case letter into one count; you're going to need to count each letter separately.  There are various ways to do that, with different ramifications for printing out the counts at the end.

Comment: I didn't realize that I put a - a instead of a-z on both capital and lower.

Comment: @Jounathaen See Again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your program, There are 2 mistakes in your program.

1. Whatever strings you type in input, everything is getting stored in `str` because of line `fgets(str,MAXLINE,stdin)` so code execution only move forward to the next line and to `getchar()`, after you press <kbd>enter</kbd> or **EOF**.See This Question [What does fgets do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445441/what-does-fgets-do) for how `fgets` work.Now Because getchar never get to work on your input whole while loop become useless.
2. Above was main problem, removing `fgets()` will allow `getchar()` to take characters and loop will work.Another Problem is in line `else if (c >= 'a'  && c <= 'a')` and line `else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'A')`, you have mistakenly instead of `z` and `Z` made them `a` and `A`, so it won't work.

Correcting Both Of These Your Code Will Work Good.

This is your program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
main()
{
char str [MAXLINE];
int ndigit, nlower, nupper, nother;
char  c;
printf("Enter any text with numbers or other characters if you like: ");
fgets(str,MAXLINE,stdin);     //What Really Happens is whatever you are
                              //inputting is getting stored into the char array str
                              //Only after you press enter or EOF then
                              // execution move forward to getchar().
  //So you type the whole string and then it all get stored in str and then 
  //comes no output because getchar never executes.

ndigit = nlower = nupper = nother = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')  
{
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                ++ndigit;
        else if (c >= 'a'  && c <= 'a') //Change To (c>='a' && c<='z')
                ++nlower;
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'A')  //Change To (c>='A' && c<='Z')
                ++nupper;
        else
                ++nother;


}
        printf("Digits : %d Lowercase Letters %d Uppercase Letters %d Other characters %d\n", ndigit, nlower, nupper, nother);
}
```

After Changing Your Code Becomes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000  //Redundant Line As You Are No Longer Using fgets.
int main()            //Changed to int main()
{

char str [MAXLINE];   //Redundant Line As You Are No Longer Using fgets.
int ndigit, nlower, nupper, nother;
char  c;
printf("Enter any text with numbers or other characters if you like: ");
ndigit = nlower = nupper = nother = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
{
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                ++ndigit;
        else if (c >= 'a'  && c <= 'z')
                ++nlower;
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                ++nupper;
        else
                ++nother;


}
        printf("Digits : %d Lowercase Letters %d Uppercase Letters %d Other characters %d\n", ndigit, nlower, nupper, nother);
}
```

Comment: You've got 4 outputs — doesn't the question say it wants 63 outputs (26 lower case letter counts; 26 upper case letter counts; 10 digit counts; and the catchall bucket for everything else)?  I agree that your fixes are necessary — and your assumption of 'contiguous alphabets' is not unreasonable (EBCDIC has gaps in its alphabets, though).

Comment: The question wasn't exactly clear and I was not able to get a hold of my professor about the question. But I do have to EOF instead of \n where I was looking around to see how to do this problem. It's a bit complicated to learn when your professor taught me same as hello world in java then out of nowhere asked to learn this. The book wasn't of much help so I turned to you guys and you guys saved me! I am really new to C so any bit of explanation helps

Comment: The explanation was great since I'm new at this c programming. The comments were nice too. If anyone got a good beginner book I can read besides The C Programming Language, it would be nice too. Thanks

Comment: @JackHuang Come Here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/134926/beginner-talk?tab=general

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sir, Can you tell me what do you mean by "EBCDIC has gaps in its alphabets, though", and i was not able to read his whole question because it was really poorly formatted , i only took his code and tried to fix it ,so was not counting everything.

Comment: You need to get a good book, that is beginner friendly you can check C programming : A Modern Perspective edition 2, it is a good book, and also check this course http://nptel.ac.in/courses/106104128/ , first do course , only 55 videos, then start reading the book.

Comment: @SurajJain Yes sorry it was poorly formatted since I myself couldn't fully understand the question of what my professor wanted. I also don't know what EBCDIC gaps mean by Johnathan Leffler. I just tried bits and pieces of knowledge of what I knew myself and since C is new to me(so is this site so I couldn't talk in the chat room) I researched as much as I could but there seems to be many ways to write this simple code. As for the Total number of characters I did add a new line ntotal = ndigit + nlower + nupper + nother; and get the total after CTRL+D.

Comment: @JackHuang  
Have You Now Understood?

Comment: @SurajJain Yes I taking your advise with the course and probably get that book. But I do understand what you did. It actually took me a lot of rewriting the code to get what I got on the top for example I didn't know EOF meant I had to CTRL+D so I threw many codes out because I didn't know why it kept going to the next line when I input something.

Comment: @JackHuang Everyone is a beginner once.

Comment: See Wikipedia on [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).  The upper-case letters are: A-I 0xC1..0xC9, J-R 0xD1..0xD9, S-Z 0xE2..0xE9.  The lower-case letters are: a-i 0x81..0x89, j-r 0x91..0x99, s-z 0xA2..0xA9.  The digits are 0xF0..0xF9.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok , i will see it , other than that part of counting each one separately , is everything ok with the answer.

Comment: Ignoring indentation, yes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That I Did not changed, same as original question.